# How do I De-Hash an Hashed Password on PHP

Tags: php, hash

I have made a basic login and signup form with HTML and PHP and MySQL...
With signing up the user I hash the password and while logging in the user, I am not able to de-hash the password. I have used the password_verify function also, but it doesn't seem to work....
What should I do???

This is My code (Login Script):-

```
   <?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {

  include 'dbh.inc.php';

  $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Username']);
  $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Password']);

  //ERROR HANDLING
  if (empty($Username) || empty($Password)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();
  } else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$Username' OR email='$Username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultcheck < 1) {
      header("Location: ../index.php?login=failure1");
      exit();
    } else {
      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //DEHASHING PASSWORD
        $hashedpwdCheck = password_verify($Password, $row["password"]);
        if ($hashedpwdCheck == false) {
          header("Location: ../index.php?login=failure2");
          exit();
        } elseif ($hashedpwdCheck == true) {
          //LOGINING IN THE USER
          $_SESSION['username'] = $row[$Username];

          header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  header("Location: ../index.php?login=failure3");
  exit();
}
```

This is the sign up form:-

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {

  include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

  $First = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['FName']);
  $Last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['LName']);
  $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Email']);
  $Email2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Email2']);
  $UName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['UName']);
  $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Password']);
  $Password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Password2']);
  $Date = date("Y-m-d");


  //ERROR HANDLING
  //CHECKING FOR EMPTY FIELDSif
  if (empty($First) || empty($Last) || empty($Email) || empty($Email2) || empty($UName) || empty($Password) || empty($Password2)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?signup=empty");
    exit();
  } else {
    //CHECKING IS INPUT IS VALID
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $First) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $Last)) {
      header("Location: ../index.php?signup=invalid");
      exit();
    } else {
      //VALIDATING Email
      if (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || !filter_var($Email2, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=email");
        exit();
      } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$UName'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultcheck > 0) {
          header("Location: ../index.php?signup=user_taken");
          exit();
        } else {
          //HASHING Password
          $hashpwd = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
          //INSERTING USER INTO DATABASE
          $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, username,    password, date_signup) VALUES ('$First', '$Last', '$Email', '$UName', '$hashpwd', '$Date');";
          mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
          echo '<script>alert("Registration Done")</script>';  
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
} else{
  header("Location: ../index.php");
  exit();
}
```

The sign up form works perfectly fine , but the login doesn't work

Comment: You *don't* "de-hash" a password.  A hash is a one-way process.  Being able to reverse it would invalidate the hash algorithm and nobody would use it anymore.  What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Avoid escaping the user entered password, just call `password_verify($_POST['Password'], $row['password'])` directly, it is safe to do so. The same goes for the password_hash() function. And make sure your database field is `varchar(255)`.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work too........

Comment: Did you try with a newly generated hash (without escaping)? Do you get an error? Could you run the script with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`? I recommend to install an IDE with a debugger, this will pay out many times.

Comment: Thank You everyone who have helped solve this bug

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

`if ($hashedpwdCheck == false)`

use

`if (password_verify($Password, $row["password"]))` //reflects true sence so chge your code accordingly

EDIT:

Please check the syntax of `$_SESSION['username'] = $row[$Username];` I have stopped using `mysql` functions so I may be wrong. I feel it should be `$_SESSION['username'] = $row[<column_name_in_your_db_table>];` `$Username` is a PHP varialble it can't be a $row value.

Moreover, also mention what is the length of your `Password` column. As per the current hash technique of `password_hash()`, the minimum length needed is 72. Better to keep it 255 for future updates.

I tried my process, your process and even with `===`. All gave the same result.

Anyways, please mention the actual error.

Comment: Since `$hashedpwdCheck` contains the result of password_verify(), how should this solve the problem?

Comment: I agree. According to me the question itself it a bit ambiguous for the part `it doesn't seem to work....`. The actual error is not mentioned. There may be a syntax error in the part `$_SESSION['username'] = $row[$Username];`. Anyways, I tried my process, author's process and even with `===`. All gave the same result.

Comment: I actually changed the char length in the Database(Varchar in My SQL)